# comando php artisan serve executando vários hosts

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo duas aplicações, uma que será meu front e outra o backend, ocorre que quando eu subo as aplicações para desenvolvimento o laravel só habilita um aplicativos, mas responde nos dois hosts.

Para ficar mais claro, exponho abaixo os dois comandos:

1. Navego até o path do sistema fo1 e executo o comando: `php artisan serve --host=fo1.dev --port=80`

> Laravel development server started on http://fo1.dev:80

2. Navego até o path do sistema fo2 e executo o comando `php artisan serve --host=fo2.dev --port=80`

> Laravel development server started on http://fo2.dev:80

Executo os comandos no prompt de comando em diferentes instâncias, mas a aplicação que sobe, é sempre a que executo no primeiro comando, como se o segundo comando fosse ignorado, apesar de a mensagem dizer que está em execução. Acessando qualquer dos dois hosts só é me apresentado o sistema do primeiro comando.

A pergunta é o seguinte, há algum comando no Laravel que eu consiga informar o path da aplicação no momento de subir o servidor do Laravel? Algo do tipo: `php serve --path=c:\sistemas\fo1 --host=fo1.dev --port=80`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está acontecendo um conflito na porta 80 da sua maquina.

Você precisa trocar a porta da segunda aplicação. Só o *hostname* não basta pois ele é somente um alias para `localhost`:

```
php artisan serve --host=fo1.dev --port=8080
php artisan serve --host=fo2.dev --port=8888
```

Para navegar você pode utilizar `fo1.dev:8080` ou `fo2.dev:8888`

Outra forma é utilizar um servidor web como Apache e fazer uso de um *virtualhost* para utilizar a mesma porta em ambos projetos. Você pode se [inspirar nesse artigo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-apache-virtual-hosts-no-ubuntu-16-04-pt) para fazer isso.